# Want to surface mount ceiling fan from outdoor lanai ceiling

Tags: ceiling-fan

I live in Florida. The lanai roof is made of a inner and outer layer of metal sandwiching internal material. I can’t recess a box so I have to use conduit to house for power. I can jump up and down on on the ceiling with no deflection and I weigh 175 lbs. I can tell from the top their are metal struts inside the ceiling spaced about every 4 feet. Can I use a fan rated pancake box screwed to the ceiling itself ? Or should I drill straight thru the ceiling which is about 5” thick and use long stainless steel nuts and bolts covered with silicone to prevent leakage. Any ideas would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Even though you can climb aboard the roof system, my concern would be the more concentrated point loads produced by the metal screw threads holding at least 17-20 pounds in tension. I like your other idea about going through the 5" roof system, especially with fender washers above.